# GCC: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in

Tags: c++, gcc

I have built GCC 4.7 on my x86 32-bit linux system. When I try to cross-compile with the -m64 flag I get the following:

> sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in

while the compiler provided by default by my Linux distribution can cross-compile with -m64.

What do I have to pass to ./configure to enable the 64bit mode in GCC? These are the options I used to build GCC 4.7:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/g++ -v Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/local/bin/g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.0/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ./configure --enable-multiarch --with-cloog=/usr/local/ --with-mpfr=/usr/local/ --with-ppl=/usr/local/ --verbose --enable-languages=c,c++
Thread model: posix gcc version 4.7.0 20120113 (experimental) (GCC)
```

EDIT:

> --enable-multilib and --enable-targets=i686-pc-linux-gnu,x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

do not change the situation. The compiler still complains about 64 bit mode not compiled in:

> $ g++ -v Using built-in specs. COLLECT_GCC=g++
>   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.0/lto-wrapper
>   Target: i686-pc-linux-gnu Configured with: ./configure
>   --enable-multiarch --with-cloog=/usr/local/ --with-mpfr=/usr/local/ --with-ppl=/usr/local/ --verbose --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-multilib --enable-targets=i686-pc-linux-gnu,x86_64-pc-linux-gnu Thread model: posix gcc version 4.7.0 20120113 (experimental) (GCC)
>
> $ g++ -m64 c.cpp  c.cpp:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not
>   compiled in

Comment: `--enable-multiarch` suggests Debian (or derivative), and as I remember, FSF's GCC doesn't really work all that well with Debian's multiarch systems. You may need to apply Debian's patches to the FSF GCC snapshots.

Comment: Of course it will not work like this. Multilib has *backward* compatibility, and not *forward*. To compile 64-bit code on 32-bit machine you have to build minimum SDK: binutils + libc [musl, uclibc, glibc, ...] + gcc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will need both binutils and gcc configured with:

```
--enable-multilib
```

and probably:

```
--enable-targets=i686-pc-linux-gnu,x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

to support multilib (the `-m64` and/or `-m32` options). You'll also need two versions of stuff like glibc to be able to link and run the resulting binaries.

Comment: It does not work with --enable-multilib and --enable-targets=i686-pc-linux-gnu,x86_64-pc-linux-gnu: $ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.0/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ./configure --enable-multiarch --with-cloog=/usr/local/ --with-mpfr=/usr/local/ --with-ppl=/usr/local/ --verbose --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-multilib --enable-targets=i686-pc-linux-gnu,x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.0 20120113 (experimental) (GCC)

Answer (score 23):

> This typically means that you're using the wrong (old) compiler.

The new compilers support both -m32 and -m64. You have to set the PATH to the new compilers (in the gcc,MinGW subdirectory of Rtools) **before** any old compilers in Rtools.

Try updating your compiler's binary lib path to 64bit version. Other resources like lib folders also should change accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Just resolved this issue.
In the environment variables, remove the entries to any outdated c++ package.

In my case, I worked in Anaconda on Windows 64-bit. In anaconda, I performed 'conda  install mingw libpython'. 
Mingw is for c++ compiler. But I had earlier installed cygwin's mingw for c++ compilations which hadn't been updated. This is the reason for conflict. 
I resolved this issue by simply removing the environment variable (PATH) corresponding to these c++ packages.
I have tried almost all forums, this solution works.

Please let me know in case anyone needs help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on windows. Despite installing codeblock 20.03 I couldn't compile my code 64 bit.
I solved it by setting the compiler to x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe instead of g++.exe. It was in the bin directory as g++.exe.
In windows go to Settings menue and:
Settings->Compiler...
select the "toolchain executables" tab and and from there on it is obvious.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issues. My solution:

Update everything (R, Rstudio, R packages) and close Rstudio.
Uninstall Rtools and install the latest version.
Add only 2 entries under Enviroment Variables/System variables/Path:
   - C:\Rtools\bin
   - C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin (!not the 32bit version)
Path entries have to be in this order and above %SystemRoot\System32
*I did NOT install in the strongly recommended default location on C:*

After that open Rstudio and re-install Rcpp via console:
install.packages("Rcpp")

Test if it's working with:
Rcpp::evalCpp("2+2")

After that just switch to the Terminal in Rstudio, go into the cmdstan source folder and type 'make build'.
*--- CmdStan v2.19.1 built ---*
Done!

Details:

```
*> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)
Matrix products: default
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250  LC_CTYPE=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250    LC_MONETARY=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250 LC_NUMERIC=C                       
[5] LC_TIME=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250    
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.0 tools_3.6.0*
```

Comment: This also helps:
https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/failing-to-install-rstan-2-18-on-win10-x64/6044

Comment: This person is not using Windows, he's using Linux.