# Building 64bit executables with g++

Tags: c++, g++, 64-bit

I build g++3.4.6 on a solaris 10 x86 machine. using this g++, i tried to build a 64 bit binary using -m64 option

```
g++ -m64 test.cpp -o test.exe
```

I didn't faced any issue with this. Then i copied the entire gcc install directory to another solaris machine (identical hardware and OS)(let us call it machine 2). But now if am trying to build a 64 bit binary, i am getting the following error

```
test.cpp:1: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
```

However, when i used another version of g++ compiler(3.4.3) available on machine 2 to build 64 bit binaries, i didn't get any error. This left me confused as

1. If this is problem with how g++ was originally build then why it works on machine 1 and not on machine 2 ?
2. If this is problem with machine, then why on machine 2, another version of the g++ compiler is able to make 64 bit binaries?

What i need to do with respect to building compiler again or with respect to machine configuration so that i will be able to build 64 bit binaries on machine 2 using g++3.4.6 ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to configure *gcc* **and** *binutils* to have the following options:

```
--enable-multilib
--enable-targets=i686-pc-linux-gnu,x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

also you will need both the 32 bit and 64 bit versions of, for example, glibc (not sure about this last bit, but thats the way my linux system is set up and seems ok for 64 bit and 32 bit compilation.

[These posts are worth a look too (from gcc help)](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2011-04/msg00523.html)

Feel free to get back to me if you need any more help, will strive to do so.

**Addendum:**

just found these posts too which may help: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861105/gcc-sorry-unimplemented-64-bit-mode-not-compiled-in)