# Can't compile yocto for Quark based Galileo Gen2

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, bitbake, intel-galileo

I have been trying bitbaking minimal yocto image, everything compiles but the kernel.

```
#bitbake yocto-image-minimal
```

or

```
#bitbake linux-yocto
```

or

```
#bitbake linux-yocto -c devshell
//and then in new dev shell terminal
# make
```

But error is consistent:

```
..
bounds.c:1:0: error: code model 'kernel' not supported in the 32 bit mode
..
bounds.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
```

I have also tried with cleansstate as well as cleanall commands with bitbake but no success.

Comment: check this link if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861105/gcc-sorry-unimplemented-64-bit-mode-not-compiled-in

Comment: I would recommend to use *meta-acpi* layer https://github.com/westeri/meta-acpi

Comment: I got the problem resolved by using official yocto 4.1 kernel as part of openembedded/meta/ recipies-kernel. Earlier, I had been using kernel layer for galileo based device. Possibly meta-acpi README has some reasons for earlier failures. Thanks +0andriy, it is useful to understand.