# GCC unable to compile Go Program

Tags: gcc, go

I wrote a very simple program in Go using using a 2D game library.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten"
    "github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/ebitenutil"
)

const screenWidth, screenHeight = 320, 240

func update(screen *ebiten.Image) error {
    ebitenutil.DebugPrint(screen, "Game test")
    return nil;
}
func main() {
    if err := ebiten.Run(update, screenWidth, screenHeight, 2, "Test"); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

This, however, relies on GCC to compile. When running, I'm prompted with this message:

```
# github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.2/glfw
cc1.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
# github.com/go-gl/gl/v2.1/gl
cc1.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
```

I attempted to download MinGW-w64 to rectify the issue, but it hasn't been successful.

How would I go about resolving this?

Answer (score 2):

So your C compiler does not support 64 bit compilation. One way to resolve this is to build in 32 bit mode. Go will by default try to build for the system architecture that you are on but you can modify that behavior by setting the environment variable `GOARCH=386` before building. On Windows you can type this into your cmd:

```
set GOARCH=386
go build
```

You could create a simple `.bat` batch script with this content and run that when you want to build.

Note that 64 bit systems will run 32 bit programs just fine. This is also a nice way to make sure that when you give the `.exe` to someone else, it will run on their system (not considering other dependencies).

If you want to upgrade your C compiler instead to build 64 bit applications, see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861105/gcc-sorry-unimplemented-64-bit-mode-not-compiled-in), maybe that helps.