# How do I correctly use 64-bit TDM-GCC with cgo?

Tags: go, cgo, tdm-gcc

I'm attempting to use a library at github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten. Regardless of what I do, I'm met with this error:

```
# github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.2/glfw
cc1.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
# github.com/go-gl/gl/v2.1/gl
cc1.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
```

I've attempted updating MinGW

> mingw-get udpate

I've set the PATH variable for MinGW.

I've downloaded MinGW-w64 [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/?source=typ_redirect).

I've gone [here](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) and downloaded the tdm-gcc 64 bundle.

And still, I'm met with the same error. How do I circumvent this?

Comment: I've had the same issue yesterday. MinGW-w64 worked for me

Comment: Why do you [keep posting the same question again and again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46925915/)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Read the [`cgo` manual](https://golang.org/pkg/cmd/cgo/),
   notice there how the `go` tool calls the compilers for the foreign
   languages it supports.
2. Run

   ```
    go env
   ```

   and see at the variables `CC` and `CXX` it'll show you:
   that are the C and C++ compilers the `go` toolchain would call to compile
   C and C++ code, respectively.

   I bet it will show "bare" names such as `gcc` and `g++`, respectively.

   Notice that when a program on Windows is being run without specifying
   its full pathname (that is, beginning with a drive letter and
   followed by that `:\` fun construct and then the rest of the path—
   ending in the actual program file's name), the program's file is looked
   up in a set of paths defined by the contents of the so-called
   [environment variable called "PATH"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)).

   That `PATH` env. variable can be system-wide and per-user;
   the latter trumps the former.
3. In a shell, run

   ```
    echo %PATH%
   ```

   and see whether there are listed any pathnames of the installed
   C/C++ compilers.
   I bet there will be a path of some 32-bit GCC but not your 64-bit suite.
4. Make sure your `PATH` env. variable contains an entry for the directory
   containing the executable program of your 64-bit compiler whose name matches
   the appropriate name listed in the `go env` output.

   Please refer to the installation manual of your compiler for more details.

If all else fails, please ask a concrete question about installing that compiler over there at the https://superuser.com.